# How to change the color of EditText after change?

Tags: android, colors

I want the change the color of an android EditText if text contains '(' and ')'. Brackets have special meaning and that string need to change the color. Please anyone help.

Comment: u mean change color of the letters?

Comment: Follow this question. Seems to be doing same thing. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055104/set-text-color-for-a-specific-text-in-android-edittext

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set text color of TextView in code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602902/how-to-set-text-color-of-textview-in-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(s.toString().contains("(") && s.toString().contains(")")){
            EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id_of_text);
            text.setTextColor(color);
        }
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
});
```

Note that you don't want to call `findViewById()` every time the text changes as it's pretty slow, so store that reference globally.

**Edit**: please note that the parameter `color` in `setTextColor()` is a color, and not a resource. So to get a color from the resource you need to use the following:

```
getResources().getColor(R.color.color_id);
```

Answer (score 3):

use [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) for EditText

example

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
                String text = s.toString();
                if(text.contains("(") || text.contains(")")) {
                    editText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                } else {
                    editText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`EditText` extends `TextView` which has a method called setTextColor(int color)

[See Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor%28int%29)

Answer (score 1):

```
   topic.setTextColor(Color.RED);   

  topic.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffff0000"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at `TextWatcher`? [(link)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

You can inspect the entered string after every change, and format it as you see fit.